# How to get positions of all CSS color decorators with VSCode API?

Tags: css, api, visual-studio-code, colors

I want my extension to be able to get the positions of all CSS color decorators.
[image]

This is my extension "Blockman":
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leodevbro.blockman

It highlights nested code blocks, but one big problem is the CSS color decorators, they make text wider by 2 char-space on each decorator, so the edges get rendered inside, because render is calculated by char count.

[image]

**If I have the positions of all the decorators, then I'll be able to correctly compute the edges of the blocks.**

Comment: `vscode.executeDocumentColorProvider` on https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

Comment: WOW, thanks so much............

Comment: And, also, is it possible to get positions of such inline annotations?
https://i.ibb.co/7Qjyds1/2021-06-18-04-07-57.png

Comment: That image has no color decorators, I have never used that function

Comment: Yeah, it's not color decorators, but it is inline annotations which is from this extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liamhammett.inline-parameters

Comment: why would there be a VSC API call that enumerates annotations but is called `Color`

Comment: that means the shown colors ARE like the extension parameters: styled decorations with `contentText`, the content is a space with background color and border

Comment: Yeah, I get it. So I guess, the only way for Blockman to compute borders correctly is to get the px locations of all the characters in each line. But I guess currently it is not possible with VSCode API, right?